# What Qt classess use to make an animation?

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote almost every sort algorithm in C++ in console. Now I would like to make it look good, so what classes of Qt should I use to make an animation of sorting algorithms I implemented in pure C++? Im a newbie in Qt ;) tia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `QGraphicsItemAnimation` to animate graphics displayed using `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView`.

Links:

- [Graphics View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html)
- [QGraphicsItemAnimation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemanimation.html)

Answer (score 3):

Outside of the Graphics View Framework, you can use `QVariantAnimation` or `QPropertyAnimation` to drive properties or methods of any `QObject` derived class.  See the Animation Framework [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html) for more info.

Conversely you can manually configure a `QTimer` to drive painting updates of a widget and use an increment to drive a `QTimeLine`.